# Position is fixed to bottom corner of page instead of bottom corner of div

Tags: html, css

I haven't coded in over a year so I'm a bit rusty. I'm trying to fix my menu to the bottom right corner of the div "wrapper", but it fixes to the bottom right corner of the screen.

```html
<div id="wrapper">

<header>

<ul id="menu">
 <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
 <li><a href="other.html">Other</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

and the css

```css
 #wrapper {
 width: 1840px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 15px;
 background-color: #F0E0B2;
 }

#menu, #menu ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 }

#menu {
 position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
 width: 759px;
 border-right: 1px solid #C0B38E;
    background-color: #F0E0B2;
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to OS! So, what is your question? What do you want to achieve. Could you provide more in your question?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it. The parent container needs `position: relative;` so that the child can be positioned properly.

```
#wrapper {
    width: 1840px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #F0E0B2;
    position: relative;
    }

#menu, #menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    }

#menu {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 759px;
    border-right: 1px solid #C0B38E;
    background-color: #F0E0B2;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp, position: fixed is relative to the browser window. You need to use position: absolute, which is relative to the closest parent div with position: relative. I believe you are wanting something similar to this (note the position:fixed on the #wrapper and position:absolute on the #menu):

```
#wrapper {
    width: 1840px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #F0E0B2;
    position: fixed;
}

#menu, #menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 759px;
    border-right: 1px solid #C0B38E;
    background-color: #F0E0B2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking like this. I hope it will helps you.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_j/o1o67ury/)**

```
#wrapper {
    width:1840px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    /*text-align: left;*/
    padding:15px;
    background-color: #F0E0B2;
    position: relative;
    }

#menu, #menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    }

#menu {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #C0B38E;
    background-color:red;
    }
ul#menu li{
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 5px;
    float: left;
    }
```